# Flag dialog no longer draggable

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, flag-dialog

Following the recent changes to the flagging system, it would appear that the flag dialog is no longer draggable.

Can this be fixed?

Edit: As noted by Aziz, it becomes draggable upon selecting the `it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate` option.

Comment: Try this: open 'flag' dialog, click on "it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate", and then come back to the main screen of the flag dialog. Now I was able to drag the dialog. I think it is a bug but here could be a workaround till then :)

Comment: @AzizShaikh as soon as you press the `it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate` option, the dialog becomes draggable again yeah. Good catch :)

Comment: Good catch, as for "it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate" it opens whole different dialog on top of the previous one. (just being picky here :))

Comment: Appears to be fixed now.